# Input tags inside backgrid table

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backgrid

I have created in [backgridjs](http://backgridjs.com/) table custom "TagCell" (with implemented [THIS](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input)).

So my cell looks like:

```
var TagCell = Backgrid.TagCell = Cell.extend({
  className: "tag-cell",
  events: {
      'click .tag a': 'removetag',
    },
  initialize: function (options) {
    TagCell.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.title = options.title || this.title;
    this.target = options.target || this.target;
    var model = this.model;
    var rawData = this.formatter.fromRaw(model.get(this.column.get("name")), model);


  },
  removetag: function(event) {
      var that = this;
      that.model.set({location: ""},{success: alert("removed!"));

  },
  render: function () {
    this.$el.empty();
    var rawValue = this.model.get(this.column.get("name"));
    var formattedValue = this.formatter.fromRaw(rawValue, this.model);
    this.$el.append('<input name="location" class="tagggs" value="'+formattedValue+'" />');
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this;
  },
});
```

If I trying to call **removetag** function with event click to ".tag" model with empty location is saved. But If I trying to call function with click event to ".tag a" or directly to class ".rmvtag" function is not called. I think because jquery tags input is designed like this:

```
 $('<span>').addClass('tag').append(
     $('<span>').text(value).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;'),
     $('<a>', {
         href  : '#',
         class : 'rmvtag',
         text  : 'x'
     }).click(function () {
         return $('#' + id).removeTag(escape(value));
     })
 ).insertBefore('#' + id + '_addTag');
```

So there is click function with removetag() written directly after append element. How can I call save model function from backbone on click to rmvtag link?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the relationship of the `<span>` you create with jQuery to your view? When do you attach that element to the DOM?

Comment: Please take a look here http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ and try inspect the tags. Span is for make text looks like tag.

Comment: I don't see where or at what point you're attaching this `<span/>`  block in your view. Could you show when this is inserted into the DOM?